# Insert into fields with special characters in the fieldname

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with what I think is pretty basic stuff in SQL:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS ([First-Name], [Last-Name]) 
VALUES (@[First-Name], @[Last-Name])
```

If I choose a column name without a special character, and leave the square brackets aside, it works.

Is there perhaps a way to allow special characters some how, that I don`t need to work with square brackets? I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server Management Studio.

Thx

Answer (score 2):

There is a way NOT to use special characters. How about field name like `!#$%`? Why can't you just use some real notations like camelCase? I mean `firstName`, `lastName`, or `first_name`, `last_name`

Comment: The Db comes was migrated from an old access file. Problem is that to many people have their hands on the Db. Renaming would be the harder way.

Comment: just tell em: `get your dirty hands outta my database!` and do it like a real man :)